# AjaxForm file upload - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using jquery.form.js plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Right after uploading the picture I would like to display it in a div. I made it work before, but unfortunately it works asynchronously and only with smaller files - when it's a bigger file, I see it's trying to display the picture that hasn't been uploaded yet. This is the code that works with small files:

```
        $(this.el).find('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(data) {
        document.cookie = "imagePath=" + data;
        var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)imagePath\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
        $('.full-picture-col').html('<img src="' + data + '" class="img-responsive" />').fadeIn('slow');
        $('.left-picture-col').hide();
        $('.right-picture-col').hide();

    });
```

I tried modifying the code so the picture gets displayed on "success", but unfortunately it doesn't work. I get an error in the console:

```
http://localhost/blabla/[object%20Object] 404 (not found).
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="api/upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" />
    <input id="upload" name="userfile" type="file" class="choose-file"/>
    <button class="choose-picture"></button>
    <div class="filename"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="send-button" value='' />
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$(this.el).find('#myForm').ajaxForm({
        complete: function(data) {
            document.cookie = "imagePath=" + data;
            var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)imagePath\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
            $('.full-picture-col').html('<img src="' + data + '" class="img-responsive" />').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.left-picture-col').hide();
            $('.right-picture-col').hide();
        }
    });
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: It looks like `data` isn't a string -- it's a JSON object of some kind. Try doing `console.log(data)` within your function so you can inspect exactly what you're being given upon completion.

Comment: I think your javascrips works fine. As @Michael0x2a said, i think your data isn't the data you are expecting. What do you see if you alert or print the `data` of your `complete` handler?